# Should I build an Alarm app in React native or build it natively for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-application

I am going to build an alarm clock app and looking for a technology.

I prefer React Native because I am a js developer and have experience in React. But after going through stuff online. I realized that it wouldn't be possible through expo.

I am wondering if building it in React native is worth the hassle and should I build it natively in Kotlin and Swift?

Looking at this for React native reference
https://github.com/baekgol/react-native-alarm-manager

Comment: This type of question isn't appropriate on this forum. It's asking for opinions and that is out of scope here.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure you'll need Expo, i think you can acomplish this with a native React app.

Answer (score 0):

Building using react-Native gives you alot of advantages like Hybrid i.e building for both ios and android with same code base

Answer (score 0):

Native application give you multiple of advatages:

1. Much faster
2. Best user expericence
3. Native UI elements
4. Access The Full Feature Set Of Device without using third party libraries
5. More functionallity
6. Avoid multiple bugs on platform update
7. Muсh safe
8. Less application volume

in the long run, these costs for development on 2 platforms are justified

there are multiple example of companie who start to develop app using hybrid and finally they switch to native

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no perfect answer to this question. You should be able to get this working with both options but I think you should think a bit about what you want to achieve developing this project.

1. Do you want to release it in the app store and earn money?
2. Do you want to learn new techs?
3. How many hours are you going to put into this project?

Take in count managing the same project with 2 different codebases and languages could be really time consuming.

In my opinion i would go with React Native. But if you want to learn Kotlin and Swift you should try with that